# graphql works locally but not in Netlify (Gatsby + Netlify CMS)

Tags: gatsby, netlify, gatsby-plugin

I am trying to inject markdown files to my Gatsby page which does work locally(Develop and Server). However, the same graphql queries fail to return data in Netlify. Seems very weird to me.

Here is a sample graphql query.

```
export const query = graphql`
  query {products_horizontal: file(
      sourceInstanceName: { eq: "products" }
      childMarkdownRemark: { frontmatter: { vertical: { eq: false } } }
    ) {
      sourceInstanceName
      childMarkdownRemark {
        frontmatter {
          title
          date
          store
          vertical
          price
          image
          templateKey
          description
          featuredpost
          featuredimage
          tag
          color
        }
      }
    }}`
```

I have added a console.log to view the contents of my data object upon build, and below is local build of my application

```
  products_horizontal: {
    sourceInstanceName: 'products',
    childMarkdownRemark: { frontmatter: [Object] }
  },
```

As you can see the product_horizontal has one Remark Node. Now when it comes to the exact same file in netlify. I get the following:

```
products_horizontal: null
```

**Note:** When I remove the `frontmatter: { vertical: { eq: false } }` from the filters it does work in Netlify as well.

I have been stuck with this error for about 6 hours now, much appreciate your help. I will now add some more code for reference.
**gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms",
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        // CommonMark mode (default: true)
        commonmark: true,
        // Footnotes mode (default: true)
        footnotes: true,
        // Pedantic mode (default: true)
        pedantic: true,
        // GitHub Flavored Markdown mode (default: true)
        gfm: true,
        // Plugins configs
        plugins: [],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: "images",
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: "products",
        path: `${__dirname}/product`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: "blogs",
        path: `${__dirname}/blog`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: "tags",
        path: `${__dirname}/tag`,
      },
    },

    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-layout",
      options: {
        component: require.resolve(`./src/components/Layout/index.tsx`),
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-intl`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/intl`,
        languages: [`en`, `az`, `ru`],
        defaultLanguage: `en`,
        redirect: false,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `false` as string (`"false"`)?